# UICollectionView zoom with scroll.

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm trying to implement a scrollview where the cells auto zoom as they near a certain point in. As a cell nears the point it will start enlarging and as it moves away - it will shrink. I've been trying to find some tutorials around this but haven't had much luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "cells auto zoom as they near a certain point in".. are you talking about something similar to the genie effect in mac osx doc? i'm just trying to visualize what u're talking about

Comment: Yes, I am basically trying to replicate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UICollectionView with a custom layout seems like the right way to do this. A UICollectionViewLayout gets to define the layout attributes for each item, including size and position. All you need to do is define a layout that positions the cells in a grid or however you like, but adjusts the size of the cells according to their distance from the point of interest.

You might find some sample code associated with the collection view talks from WWDC 2012 -- there were some interesting layouts shown there.

Comment: Thanks found a nice flow demo from the WWDC '12 session!